# how do i create an empty collection with properties

Tags: mongodb

i want to create an empty collection , with properties which contains field_Name and field_type in the form of key and value.

db.createCollection("studentInfo1",{
                            properties : {

```
                                 stdid :{
                                         bsonType: "int" 
                                         } ,
                                  name : {
                                          bsonType : "string"
                                         }       
                                     } 
                                });
```

{
    "ok" : 0.0,
    "errmsg" : "The field 'properties' is not a valid collection option. Options: { properties: { stdid: { bsonType: \"int\" }, name: { bsonType: \"string\" } } }",
    "code" : 72,
    "codeName" : "InvalidOptions"
}

Comment: Please refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/, it seems you are not using the createCollection method correctly. Also it seems you want to use mongodb in a RMDB way, which can't be achieved without using external libraries. In mongodb you do not need to create the structure first before you can insert documents into your collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create a script to do the work; then you can do something like this:

```
db.createCollection("collectionName");
var collectionName = db.getCollection("collectionName");
var someData = { number: 10, name : "John" };
collectionName.insert(someData);
```